# What permission is required to deploy release?

Tags: continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines, release

What permission is required to allow a user to manually deploy (or redeploy) a stage in an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The permissions are set on each release pipeline itself:

[image]

"Manage Deployments" allows users to come in and deploy to their environment without allowing them to edit the pipeline.

[image]